# (C++) Как заблокировать перемещение мыши?

Tags: c++

делаю внутри игровое меню и столкнулся с проблемой, как заблокировать мышь?

```
BlockInput(true)
```

Мне не подходит, т.к. он требует во-первых UAC, а во-вторых блокирует и саму клавиатуру, а выбор функций в меню происходит у меня как раз с помощью стрелочек на клавиатуре.

Какие есть варианты?

Comment: вариантов средствами чистого C++ нет — стоит уточнить в рамкох какого фреймворка/платформы/API/ОС вопрос...

Comment: Непонятна связь *"внутри игровое меню"* <-> *"заблокировать мышь"*. Ну показываете меню. А зачем что-то блокировать?

Comment: Под заблокировать вы имеете в виду скрыть?

Comment: Можно и WinAPI использовать, Windows. Внутриигровое меню - в оверлее делаю наложение меню на игру. Когда оно открыто, то мышкой нельзя двигать, тоесть она заблокирована должна быть.

Comment: Перехватывайте сообщения MOUSE_MOVE (или как оно там..) и пропускайте